# last.ckpt | RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:145] . PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am using `JupyterLab` on `AWS SageMaker`. Kernel: `conda_pytorch_latest_p36`.

I have successfully performed training.

Now, I attempt to set up the model for predictions, i.e. testing.

I suspect `last.ckpt` file is corrupt; as it fails on line:

```py
model = OntologyTaggerModel.load_from_checkpoint('last.ckpt.2cCC2f52', map_location=torch.device(device), from_checkpoint=True)
```

---

**Where does `last.ckpt` file come from - BERT download or my own model definition?**

**How do I regenerate it?**

Update: I was able to re-generate it: `last.ckpt.E342d53e`.

Run model load with `last.ckpt.**E342d53e**`:

```py
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:145] . PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

Run model load with `last.ckpt` (without unique string in filename):

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/last.ckpt'
```

I launched a new `AWS SageMaker` instance without luck.

---

Suspect Code (2nd last line):

```py
def get_device():
    device = 'cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    return device

def preprocess(input, preprocessor):
    result = [torch.tensor(preprocessor.tokenise(i)).unsqueeze(dim=0) for i in input]
    result = torch.cat(result)
    return result
def predict_fn(input, model_artifacts):
    preprocessor, model, label_mapper = model_artifacts
    # Pre-process
    input_tensor = preprocess(input, preprocessor)
    # Copy input to gpu if available
    device = get_device()
    
    input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device=device)
    # Invoke
    model.eval()
    classes = []
    probs = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        output_tensors = model(input_tensor)[1]
        # Convert to probabilities
        softmax = torch.nn.Softmax()
        for class_index, output_tensor in enumerate(output_tensors):
             output_tensor = softmax(output_tensor)
             prob, predictions = torch.max(output_tensor, dim=1)   
             classes.append(label_mapper.reverse_map(predictions, class_index))
             probs.append(prob)
        classes = [c for c in zip(*classes)]   
        probs = [c for c in zip(*probs)]

    return classes, probs

device = get_device()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
label_mapper = LabelMapper('classes.txt')
model = OntologyTaggerModel.load_from_checkpoint('last.ckpt.2cCC2f52', map_location=torch.device(device), from_checkpoint=True) # CRASH !
model = model.to(device)
```

Traceback:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ba98e0974205> in <module>
     36 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
     37 label_mapper = LabelMapper('classes.txt')
---> 38 model = OntologyTaggerModel.load_from_checkpoint('last.ckpt.2cCC2f52', map_location=torch.device(device), from_checkpoint=True)
     39 model = model.to(device)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py in load_from_checkpoint(cls, checkpoint_path, map_location, hparams_file, strict, **kwargs)
    131         """
    132         if map_location is not None:
--> 133             checkpoint = pl_load(checkpoint_path, map_location=map_location)
    134         else:
    135             checkpoint = pl_load(checkpoint_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/cloud_io.py in load(path_or_url, map_location)
     44     fs = get_filesystem(path_or_url)
     45     with fs.open(path_or_url, "rb") as f:
---> 46         return torch.load(f, map_location=map_location)
     47 
     48 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    585             # reset back to the original position.
    586             orig_position = opened_file.tell()
--> 587             with _open_zipfile_reader(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
    588                 if _is_torchscript_zip(opened_zipfile):
    589                     warnings.warn("'torch.load' received a zip file that looks like a TorchScript archive"

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in __init__(self, name_or_buffer)
    240 class _open_zipfile_reader(_opener):
    241     def __init__(self, name_or_buffer) -> None:
--> 242         super(_open_zipfile_reader, self).__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
    243 
    244 

RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:145] . PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

Please let me know if I should add anything else.

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS SageMaker, but I did not understand where you got the `last.ckpt` from ? The training code is more important than the inference code.